# Regular expression to parse PnPID

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get the value of vendor ID and device ID from a PnPID, for example, I want to get the vendor ID "8086" and device ID "24D5" from the below string.

```
pci\ven_8086&dev_24D5&subsys_02871014
```

my code is (in C#)

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"dev_\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string text = @"pci\ven_8086&dev_2425&subsys_02871014";
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(watch);
}
```

But this does not remove the prefixing "dev_" for me, and it can not match a device ID which contains hexdecimal digits. What is the right expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a group using parentheses:

```
new Regex(@"dev_(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then in second group you will get just digits (first is always reserved for string that is matched by whole regex).

To match hexdecimal value use:

```
new Regex(@"dev_([0-9a-f]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

To match both - device and vendor - in one regex, use:

```
new Regex(@"ven_([0-9a-f]+)&dev_([0-9a-f]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you, as for the prefixing "dev_" I can do it in one more step, :)

Comment: @kennyzx If you find an answer as correct one, remember to accept it (also in your recent questions).